# c# WCF problems speed

Tags: c#, wcf

I have to do many serialization communication between two computers, i am now using WCF for this, but the time it takes to complete an operation is 10k - 20k ticks, this is too much for my communication, i've also tried direct TCP/IP serialization the results of this were much more promesing, about 1k-2k ticks per operation. I'd realy like to stick with WCF because of it's simplicity,I also noticed that WCF cannot handle multiple operations at the same time, this is also something that is needed. is there any way to do this, may with something else then WCF? or am i stuck with writing my own TCP/IP serialization communication?

This is how i do a request:

```
pipeFactory = new ChannelFactory<IBlissRequest>(binding, new EndpointAddress(ep));
pipeProxy = tempPipeFactory.CreateChannel();
((IClientChannel)pipeProxy).Open();
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Restart();
string returnString = pipeProxy.SystemRequest("name", "somthing more", "some data");
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);
```

This is the Interface that is used:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IBlissRequest
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SystemRequest(string InstanceName, string MethodName, string Parameters);
}
```

The method that is executed in the interface is empty so does almost not consume ticks

Comment: "it takes to complete an operation is 10k - 20k ticks", please post your code for this. And What do you mean by this statement "I also noticed that WCF can not handle multiple operations at the same time"? It can handle multiple operations at the same time.

Comment: WCF doesn't offer great performace, it is simple to program, but not appropriate if you need performance. Ir has too much overhead.

Comment: @Rafa - That strikes me as a very broad statement; can you provide your reasons for stating that?

Comment: @EhsanUllah i will try to post some of the code, what i ment with not being able to do multiple operations at thesame time, is that if i do a wcf opperation to a client, and this hangs for a second that in that time if i want to do an other opperation the first one has to complete first.

Comment: @Jeff It blocks because YOUR code blocks. If you use the asynchronous methods provided, it won't.

Comment: @Jeff in that case you should consider making Async calls.

Comment: @Tim: I have no really measurements that I can show you, this statement is based solely on my experience. I've implemented several web services and today I prefer to use REST web services (no SOAP) with lightweight or no frameworks. ServiceStack is in my opinion an easier .net framework for web services.

Comment: @Rafa - Fair enough (I deal almost 100% on the SOAP side).  I would agree in general that SOAP is heavier, but I've seen some good response times with WCF SOAP when care is taken to write the service well :)

Comment: @Rafa What is a good response time? then i know if i must cuntinue with WCF or create my own.

Comment: @Jeff - I cannot really tell, it depends on your data structures for the HTTP body and its serialization and many other factors and how all this process is done. I don't use figures, I've never measured frameworks by myself, but there are some comparisons in the internet. But if you have to optimize the performance, think about your DAOs and think about the serializations. Think about all the levels of abstraction that your framework introduces and compare.

Comment: @Tim - You're right, a good written SOAP service is as fast as a REST service. The only problem is that all the abstraction that SOAP offers makes you easier to forget that you're writing a web service :)

Comment: Don't forget that creating a ChannelFactory instance is an expensive operation. You should use strategies to reuse the instance you create to overcome this challenge.

Also, the binding you use also influences the performance you can obtain when dealing with service communication.

Comment: @SergioVicente, i create one channelfactory at the first communication, and i save it for the next operations. this is the binding i use : 'NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
                        binding.ListenBacklog = 1000;
                        binding.MaxConnections = 1000;' what can i do to improve it?

Comment: @EhsanUllah i did convert my code to async now, but it still does not complete multiple requests at thesame time, if one thread uses the wcf to conmunicate to a server, and a second thread does thesame, one has to complete before the otherone starts. how can i fix this?

Comment: @Jeff please keep a user state integer value and pass it to every call with userstate++

Answer (score 2):

Some production performance issues with both WCF services and using the WCF clients (ClientBase or ChannelFactory directly) are due to the .NET garbage collector being forced to do a lot of work because of sloppy object disposal. I'd use Performance Monitor to check the behavior of the .NET garbage collector at runtime to see if this is causing the spikes.

If it is a GC issue then you need to do a review of your service and client code. On the service, ensure object instance scope is as limited as possible. This helps ensure instance are mostly garbage collected in Gen0 which occurs most often. The client code should also be reviewed but it is particularly important in the service code.

Also, in both the service but particularly on the client, make sure object instances that implement IDisposable are properly wrapped in a using statement EXCEPT for the WCF client instance. To handle the proper disposal of the WCF client, look at this [brief blog post](http://omaralzabir.com/do-not-use-using-in-wcf-client/) for a good pattern. This can get tricky if you are using a dependency injection container. You can search for "WCF do not use using" for more detail information on why. The BasicHttpBinding and some configurations of the WsHttpBinding can handle sloppy disposal but any binding that uses sessions will be prone to the GC issues.

After some googling i found this :
**[Creating high performance WCF services](http://weblogs.asp.net/sweinstein/archive/2009/01/03/creating-high-performance-wcf-services.aspx)**

Comment: Not quite true. WCF uses BufferManager to avoid creating and disposing small objects. Any GC issues are much more likely due to user code

Answer (score 0):

If you set your service to be **single instance** with **multiple occurrence**, you should avoid some overhead.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class LessOverheadService: IService
```

Then as you noticed using a net.tcp binding is faster than http ones (since there's less overhead).

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IService" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: i ame not sure if i understand you corectly, is there a way to force WCF over TCP/IP directly instead of HTTP? becouse what i ment with that i used TCP/IP is that i made a socket and did the sending and serialisation on my own. how do i force WCF to not use HTTP but TCP/IP instead?

Comment: Ah oke, i did now know that that configured it to TCP/IP, (it already was NetTcpBinding)